# CKAN: ImportError no module named static

Tags: ckan

I'm installing CKAN from here:http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html

In step 6 I'm getting an ImportError on webob

```
ImportError: no module named static
```

This is webob version 1.0.8, which is what is listed in the requirements.txt, but I'm guessing it's the wrong version or there's a requirement I'm missing. I've tried different versions of webob too. Anyone solve this previously?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may not have activated your virtualenv.  Try running the following before you run the paster command:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
```

Comment: Thanks, it was running in virtualenv though.